# How to consume a file uploaded by WebClient.UploadFile (.NET) in a SpringBoot controller?

Tags: c#, spring-boot, file-upload, webclient

I have a mobile app written in .NET (Unity) where a user can upload an audio file that I store in my SQL database. As I like simple solutions without much code, I am using WebClient's UploadFile method:

```
client.UploadFile(uriAddress, filePath);
```

I am uploading the file to a Spring Boot API, but I don't know how I should consume it on the API's end?

```
@PostMapping("/uploadAudio")
public void uploadAudio(MultipartFile file)
{
    SessionAudio audio = new SessionAudio();
    try {
        audio.setAudio(file.getBytes());
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }

    audios.save(audio);
}
```

Is this supposed to work? I get following exception in my API:

```
org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.MultipartStream$MalformedStreamException: Stream ended unexpectedly
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.MultipartStream.readHeaders(MultipartStream.java:520) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.findNextItem(FileUploadBase.java:880) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.hasNext(FileUploadBase.java:949) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:285) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2846) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParameters(Request.java:3185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParameter(Request.java:1116) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParameter(RequestFacade.java:381) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:84) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:791) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1417) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_151]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_151]
```

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I already did, and it didn't work. I added the error to my original post.